# Perl: After Chomping a string, it does not print the string's value

Tags: regex, perl, chomp

So I am currently trying to write a perl script that reads to a file and writes to another. Currently, the problem that I have been having is removing new line characters from parsed rows.I feed in a file like this

```
BetteDavisFilms.txt
1.
Wicked Stepmother (1989) as Miranda
A couple comes home from vacation to find that their grandfather has …
2.
Directed By William Wyler (1988) as Herself
During the Golden Age of Hollywood, William Wyler was one of the …
3.
Whales of August, The (1987) as Libby Strong
Drama revolving around five unusual elderly characters, two of whom …
```

Ultimately I am trying to put it into a format like this

```
1,Wicked Stepmother ,1989, as Miranda,A couple comes home from vacation to …
2,Directed By William Wyler ,1988, as Herself,During the Golden Age of …
3,"Whales of August, The ",1987, as Libby Strong,Drama revolving around five…
```

---

it sucessfully removes recognizes to each number but then I want to remove the \n then replace the "." with a ",". Sadly the chomp function destroys or hides the data some how so when I print after chomping $row, nothing shows... What should I do to correct this?

```
#!bin/usr/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "BetteDavisFilms";
my @stack = ();

open (my $in , '<', "$file.txt" ) or die "Could not open to read \n ";
open (my $out , '>', "out.txt" ) or die "Could not out to  file  \n";

my @array = <$in>;

sub readandparse() {
    for(my $i = 0 ; $i < scalar(@array); $i++) {
        my $row = $array[$i];

        if($row =~ m/\d[.]/) {
            parseFirstRow($row);
        }
    }
}

sub parseFirstRow() {
    my $rowOne = shift;
    print $rowOne; ####prints a number
    chomp($rowOne);
    print $rowOne; ###prints nothing
    #$rowOne =~ s/./,/;
}

#call to run program
readandparse();
```

Comment: `open my $in, '<:crlf', "file.txt";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lines end with CR LF. You remove the LF, leaving the CR behind. Your terminal is homing the cursor on CR causing the next line output to overwrite the last line output.

```
$ perl -e'
   print "XXXXXX\r";
   print "xxx\n";
'
xxxXXX
```

Fix your input file

```
dos2unix file
```

or remove the CR along with the LF.

```
s/\s+\z//   # Instead of chomp
```

Comment: You mean `s/\R\z//`, I presume.

Comment: @tchrist, If your have to deal with a format for which trailing whitespace is significant, I pity you, and you'd use `s/\R\z//`. For the rest of us, `s/\s+\z//` is better.

Comment: @Joshua, That won't help. He doesn't have LF LF; he has CR LF.